# How to pass default value to custom field to reference other field

Tags: custom-object

I have an custom object name `PowerPlantIntroduce__c` and have two fields:

The first one is `pictureUrl__c` (Data Type: URL. Used to save picture's URL from Cloudinary).

The second one is `pitcture__c` (Data Type: Rich Text Area. Used to display the image from Cloudinary have URL save in field number one).

I don't know how to get the URL from field one to display the picture in field two. Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the Picture__c as a Formula Text field and use the Image formula function to display the image from the URL field

```
IMAGE(PictureUrl__c, 'image')
```